# HTTP API Call return 404 while the JSON string returned

Tags: json, vb.net, api, winforms, get

I have a DHL API GET to retrieve some data in JSON string. When I run in the uipath and it returns error 404 with the JSON data downloaded.

When I try to execute the same API call in .NET it gives a 404 error as well. How do I skip this error and continue download the JSON data?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim hwr As HttpWebRequest
    hwr = WebRequest.Create("https://api-eu.dhl.com/track/shipments?trackingNumber=7769648935/")
    hwr.Headers("DHL-API-Key") = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

    Dim wr As WebResponse
        wr = hwr.GetResponse()

        If CType(wr, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim st As Stream
            st = wr.GetResponseStream()
            Dim sr As StreamReader
            sr = New StreamReader(st)
            Dim res As Boolean
            res = sr.ReadToEnd()
            If res Then
                '...work with result...
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: With a 404, you may get a response with the content of the reason why you got a 404. If that *reason* is posted, it's in the Response object you can get from the `WebException`, so catch the exception, get the Response object and read its Stream. -- All status codes above 399 are treated as exceptions, so you always need a try/catch block when issuing a WebRequest.

Comment: You also need to learn how to declare and dispose of the disposable objects you create.